# Probability of two dice roll $(1,2)$

Tags: probability

I have two dice, we roll them once and we are currently searching to find what is the probability of getting the outcome $(1,2)$.

My take is that the probability will be $\frac{1}{36}$ but my tutor says it's $\frac{1}{21}$, please help me to understand why is that. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would say it is either $\frac1{36}$ or $\frac1{18}$, depending on whether $(2,1)$ is a distinct outcome to  $(1,2)$ [a total of $36$ equally likely outcomes] or the same outcome [a total of $21$ outcomes but not equally likely].    If it is the same outcome, then $(1,2)$ is twice as likely as $(1,1)$ while  your tutor  would apparently disagree.

Comment: Is it possible for you to get a new tutor?

Answer (score 6):

The event space for the two dice is a set of all possible pairs of outcomes, denoted as $Ω$:

$$Ω = \{{\color{#3cb4ff}{(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (1,6),}\\
(2,1), \color{#3cb4ff}{(2,2), (2,3), (2,4), (2,5), (2,6),}\\
(3,1), (3,2), \color{#3cb4ff}{(3,3), (3,4), (3,5), (3,6),}\\
(4,1), (4,2), (4,3), \color{#3cb4ff}{(4,4), (4,5), (4,6),}\\
(5,1), (5,2), (5,3), (5,4), \color{#3cb4ff}{(5,5), (5,6),}\\
(6,1), (6,2), (6,3), (6,4), (6,5), \color{#3cb4ff}{(6,6)}\}}$$

If two dice are identical. Then, there is $21$ unique outcomes $\color{#3cb4ff}{(\text{Colored)}}$.

Most probably, OP's tutor has identified these $21$ distinct outcomes from rolling two identical dice.

Someone might state that the probability of obtaining the outcome $(1,2)$ is $\frac{1}{21}$.

$\color{#00e63d}{\text{But, there is bit mistake. You can not assume the probability of all $21$ outcomes are same.}}$

Each diagonal outcome has $\frac{1}{36}$ probability$\color{blue}{(\text{Colored)}}$. Where, for other $15$ outcomes, each outcome has $\frac{2}{36}=\frac{1}{18}$.

$$Ω = \{{\color{blue}{(1,1),}(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (1,6),\\
(2,1),\color{blue}{(2,2),}  (2,3), (2,4), (2,5), (2,6),\\
(3,1), (3,2),\color{blue}{(3,3),} (3,4), (3,5), (3,6),\\
(4,1), (4,2), (4,3), \color{blue}{(4,4),}(4,5), (4,6),\\
(5,1), (5,2), (5,3), (5,4), \color{blue}{(5,5),} (5,6),\\
(6,1), (6,2), (6,3), (6,4), (6,5), \color{blue}{(6,6)}\}}$$

---

**Correct answer:**

For identical dice, the probability of obtaining any specific outcome, such as $(1,2)$, is $\frac{2}{36}
=\frac{1}{18}$
.This is because there are two ways to achieve this result: $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$.

However, if the dice are distinguishable, the total number of outcomes becomes $6\times6=36$, and the probability of any specific outcome, including $(1,2)$, is
$\frac{1}{36}$.

Comment: Great answer and visual! I'd debate $1/36$ and $1/18$ based on assumptions but never even *considered* $1/21$ before dismissing it.